# Flex container overflow if previous sibling is floated

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

If a previous sibling is set to `float` with a width of 100% and the following sibling set to `display: flex`, the latter overflow the parent container instead of wrap to a new line.

With any other `display` value but `flex` (or `grid`) it wraps, as it should, so how come it won't when set to `flex`

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.display-flex {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
}


/* Demo css */

.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-left">I'm floating left, with a width of 100%.</div>
  <div class="display-flex">'Floating left' takes up 100% of the space, but still i don't go onto a new line?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If you make it `inline-flex` it will wrap though. I guess this might be a Flexbox bug you found, but since all browser has the same behavior, it can be by design. Let us know what you want to accomplish and we'll find you a workaround

Comment: Ubby, I edited your question so it is more clear this has nothing to do with `.display-flex` _not_ being a flex item, it is about it being a flex container.

Comment: @LGSon: Not a bug. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason a block box appears to wrap when its previous sibling is a float with 100% width is because [it's not actually the box that's wrapping, it's its inline content that's wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211208/why-doesnt-a-fixed-width-element-take-up-the-space-beside-a-floated-element/43238855#43238855).

The reason this doesn't happen with a flex container is because [floats cannot intrude into flex formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). In fact, the same thing happens with block formatting contexts — if you apply `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` to the following sibling without `display: flex` the following sibling will seem to disappear altogether. (This implies that the first paragraph is true only when the block box does *not* establish a block formatting context.)

Since your float is 100% width, the flex container's (auto) width is reduced to 0. Its inline descendants don't wrap underneath the float, because those inline descendants are participating in an inline formatting context that's within an anonymous flex item, which itself doesn't wrap since it's the only flex item in the flex container. This flex item is overflowing the flex container; however the flex container itself doesn't overflow the containing block since its used width is 0, allowing it to sit next to the float.

The reason the flex container *will* wrap if it is `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: flex` is because an inline-level flex container behaves just like any other inline-level content, wrapping around a float. In this case, it's the flex container *itself* that wraps — its inline content is still formatted as an anonymous flex item, because [flex layout is identical regardless of whether the flex container itself is inline-level or block-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex/27459133#27459133).

Comment: Can you please  explain why, when i add `border: solid` to `display-flex` item, it act as expect?

Comment: @Duannx: Adding a border causes the total width of the flex container to be greater than zero, causing it to shift underneath the float since there is no longer any room for it, as described in [section 9.5 of CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats).

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the element `.display-flex` is not a flex item. It is a child element in a standard block container.

Therefore, the `flex` shorthand property, and its longhand component properties, which apply only to flex items, are having no effect.

However, the `width` property works on both flex items and containers.

More details here: [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

Comment: I just tested it with various `display` values and it will wrap to any value but `flex` and `grid`.

Comment: Now we got a great explanation from Boltclock :)

Comment: Maybe you ought to delete (or correct) this since it doesn't actually answer the question?

Comment: @LGSon, I posted this answer in response to the original question, where the difference between `flex-basis` and `width` played a prominent role. You then altered the question based on your understanding of the OP's thinking process. But the OP has yet to respond to any of your comments or edits.

Comment: You may be correct that my answer is no longer necessary. But I would like to wait for feedback from the OP before deleting it.

Comment: If to assume the OP missed the fact that the `display: flex` were to be set on the `container` and thought the `.display-flex` was a flex item and should apply the given `flex: 0 0 100%;`,  I of course invalidated your answer with my edit. Sorry for that, will be more careful next time, prior to such an edit, and hope I understood OP correct :)

Comment: @LGSon, I'm not meaning to imply that you were incorrect or that your edits are not valid. I just think the OP should be given a chance to review everything before we start deleting stuff.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you very much for notifying me, and the edit made it more clear to understand (for me :)